# EMS : The Session was closed due to an unrecoverable error

Tags: spring-jms, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, ems

I'm using SAP event mesh(EMS) for communication between events and sap JMS library(`com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.xbem`) for listening to messages from queue. But recently I have encountered exception while doing any operation and the exception is

> javax.jms.IllegalStateException : The Session was closed due to an unrecoverable error

One example is while calling `session.createQueue(queueName)`. After 1-2 days of inactivity the system goes to idle state and our application is no more able to listen to the EMS queues and because of that the data remain in the queue. It started working as expected after a fresh start.
I did some analysis on the issue and found this workaround to set `spring.jms.servicebus.idle-timeout` property. But it usually decreases the usability of the JMS starter. So, Can anyone please suggest some other solution to resolve this error?

Comment: I would try to approach the [authors of the SAP JMS library](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/02/22/please-welcome-sap-event-mesh-new-name-for-sap-cloud-platform-enterprise-messaging/). Maybe you can ask the question in [their sample repo](https://github.com/SAP-samples/event-mesh-client-java-samples)? You can potentially find more contacts in [their documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/bf82e6b26456494cbdd197057c09979f/Cloud/en-US/df532e8735eb4322b00bfc7e42f84e8d.html). I'm afraid you will have to provide a bit more details, e.g. logged (related) error messages, stacktraces, etc.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDümont for your response and time! Any updates on this? Were you able to contact someone from the authors of SAP JMS library?

Comment: Hi @NEHA, please reach out to the maintainers of the JMS library via one of the channels Alex suggested yourself. The comment section of the [Blog Post](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/02/22/please-welcome-sap-event-mesh-new-name-for-sap-cloud-platform-enterprise-messaging/), for example seems to be rather active with regards to answering questions.

Comment: @JohannesSchneider Thanks for your suggestion. It helped

Answer (score 0):

I have tried upgrading my library and then added some reconnection logic in case of any exceptions as mentioned in the [link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13564065/getting-security-session-expired-while-connecting.html) and it is working fine now.